# How did the base flood in Silent Sea?

Tags: moon, silent-sea

When characters die of exposure, they do not produce an infinite amount of water. They only produce until shortly after death (when the cells themselves run out ATP/ADP). How then could the body of the guy who died in the basement produce enough water to flood the entire base?

If the plants were capable of this feat, then the base would have already been flooded because the plants only grew because of the water.

Comment: "*Thus, they secretly started experimenting with lunar water at Balhae Lunar Station. However, the molecular structure of lunar water differed from that of Earth’s water. Dr. Song explained that it contained some kind of extraterrestrial virus. When the Lunar Water came into contact with a living host, it started multiplying inside the host’s body until the host was alive. Because of uncontrolled multiplication, the lunar water killed its host.*" - https://dmtalkies.com/the-silent-sea-ending-explained-2021-netflix-series-luna-water/

Comment: Presumably some of the cells in a body remain alive for quite some time after death

Comment: Then the base would already be flooded from the people who died in the incident.

Comment: In that case it's just crap writing.

Comment: Crap writing, crap acting, crap all around.  Is there a way to close a question based on crappy source material?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what we could see on the show, I presume the idea was that the plants (which did not die as quickly as drowning humans, maybe?) were the main driver of the water generation.

Note that during the original incident, only a small amount of plant material was present (possibly just the initial seed capsule), so it didn't contribute much to water generation. Then, *somehow*, the plants would keep growing (though how they'd do that without much more water and sunlight, down in that basement, is anyone's guess).

By the time the show's protagonists are in Balhae Station, the plants have grown to a considerable size, filling much of the rooms around the hidden storage area. At this point, one of the humans has a very bloody wound (one from which he does not die immediately, but presumably bleeds to death for quite a while), which gets in contact with one of the lunar water canisters.

Presumably, the water generated from this very bloody wound, combined with the large volume of plants, suffices to make the water replicate at such explosive rates.